# How can I make Atlas stones loadable and calibrate-able?

Tags: weightlifting, gym, exercise-equipment, plates

I'm trying to make barbell loadable atlas stones that have accurate weights. Like, say, 50lbs, 100lbs, and 200lbs. It's hard to accurately calibrate the weight of atlas stones I would imagine as their weight goes down as the cement dries over time, but certainly it can be estimated vis-a-vis the volume. Anyway, that's the weeds, ideally I'd make a custom mold with 50mm diameter cylinder passing through the center, but what I have is a solid atlas stone, and I'm thinking I can bore a 50mm hole with a masonry bit I actually already have with my large drill press, but once the hole is drilled, how then can I calibrate the weight to be heavier or lighter to have precise standard weights in 50lbs, 100lbs, and 200lbs?

---

Just in case it's not clear what I'm describing:

[image]

Comment: What you've described reminds me of the ["stone of steel"](https://www.mbpowercenter.com/stone-of-steel/), which you may find suitable for your purposes.  I have no affiliation with that website/business/product.

Comment: Just realized I'm constrained by a sleeve length of 44.5cm (17.5in), so the atlas stone will have to have a sphere diameter less than that to accommodate collars, so if I want heavier weights, I'm going to have to substitute the volume constraint with density. That is, since I can't have an atlas stone larger than my sleeve length, then if I want to have heavier weights I'll have to add heavier material in with the concrete... Anyway, I'm probably alone in my excitement. ^_^

Comment: @ChristianConti-Vock, is that loadable? I don't think it is. It's interesting, but it's also not a homogenous solid.

Comment: The "stone of steel" is loadable with Olympic barbell plates.  I'm sorry, though -- now that I see the image that you added, it's clear to me that I completely misunderstood what you want.  I have no suggestions, but I wish you well.

Comment: So you want to be able to put any of the stones on and hold it with a clamp?